# Binding prefWidthProperty of ListView to widthProperty of containing AnchorPane breaks resizing of AnchorPane

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I have a `TabPane` which contains two `Tab`s and is set up in `FXML`. On initialization I dynamically add an `AnchorPane` to one of the `Tab`s. I then set a `ListView` as a child of the `AnchorPane`:

```
AnchorPane questionPane = new AnchorPane();
questionPane.setId("questionPane");
ListView questionList = new ListView();
questionPane.getChildren().add(questionList);
```

This works perfectly fine. For debugging purposes I gave the `AnchorPane` an orange background (via `CSS`) and when I now resize the window, the `AnchorPane` get's resized as expected.
But as soon as I add the following line to the code, the `AnchorPane` can only grow and doesn't shrink anymore, resulting in outsizing my window:

```
questionList.prefWidthProperty().bind(questionPane.widthProperty());
```

Can anyone please explain, why this line breaks the resizing of the `AnchorPane`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you didn't specify the anchoring of the ListView:

```
AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(questionList , 8.0);
AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(questionList , 5.0);
AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(questionList , 8.0);
AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(questionList , 5.0);
```

The binding is not needed anymore.

Comment: But do You have any idea, why the binding breaks up the resizing?

Comment: I think the AchorePane has it own re size policy towards its children. Thus what happens is the AnchorePane width changes, thus causing a change in questionList prefWidth(due to the binding). Now because of its own resize ploicy then pane changes width which causes then the ListView to change width and the story goes on...